# what is validated first ? FormGroup or FormControls in reactive forms?

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-reactive-forms

Consider a form with two date controls. For instance, FirstDate and LastDate.
Form needs to be designed using reactive forms. Both the controls has 3 validatios each. 
1) Date should be required.
2) Date should not be before 30days from the current day.
3) FirstDate should be before LastDate.

I am trying to handle first two validations with formcontrol validations. And the last i.e comparison validation with FormGroup validation.

```
 datesFormGroup: this.formBuilder.group(
  {
    firstDateCtrl: ['', [Validators.required,validateRange]],
    lastDateCtrl: ['', [Validators.required,validateRange]],
  },
  { validator: validateDateForm }
)
```

I am validating formControl to check whether the dates selected are not before 30days using custom validator `validateRange`.

```
validateRange(dateControl: AbstractControl){
  if(!dateControl.errors){
      ....
      dateControl.setError({range:true})
  }
}
```

Furthermore,I have custom validator `validateDateForm` to compare both dates and check that first date is before last date.

```
validateDateForm((dateForm: FormGroup) ){
  if(!dateControl.errors){ 
    ... 
    ....
    ...
    check and set error
    dateGroup.controls.firstDate.setErrors({ compare: true });
 }
}
```

After debugging this snippet, I found that dateControl in `validateRange` has compare error. Does this means `validateDateForm` executes before  `validateRange`.

Does FormGroup Validations executes before FormControl validations?

Comment: I don't think it matters which one gets validated firstly (I think it's an implementation detail). They both run and you can use the both to display an error to the user. It's up to you what you write in the validator.

Comment: I think you have to create two custom validators as your requirement and validate your  form controls no need to validate form group.